# Zend Framework 2: how do I access functions across modules?

Tags: php, module, zend-framework2

I am not sure if this is possible, so please let me know.

I have a modular setup of Zend Framework currently with only 2 modules:

sms
web

```
application
--- /forms
--- /models
--- /modules
------/sms/
---------/models
------/web/
---------/models
```

Is it at all possible to access the functions (Models) in the SMS module from the WEB module?

Lets say I was in the IndexController in the WEB module and wanted to call the getData() Model in the SMS module, is this possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

More ZF2 specific way, using namespace, would be:

```
use MySmsModule\Model\MySmsModel;

class WebController extends ActionController
{
    public function indexAction()
    {
        $MySmsModel = new MySmsModel();
        $data = $MySmsModel->getData();

        ...
    }
}
```